# How to hide the overflow image on the bottom right with animation?

Tags: html, css, animation

I was wondering if it is possible to hide parts of an image that is positioned with negative px?

Essentially I would like to hide the image part on the very right of the screen that goes past the pink div and purple div. I would also like to hide the image part that goes downwards into the purple part. So only the image on the pink div is visible.

[snippet of animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWMgJ.jpg)

I have used the animation property to set the positions on page load.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#div1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
}

#dog1 {
  animation: fadeIn 3s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  left: -100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
    left: -100px;
  }
  100% {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
}

#div2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: purple;
  z-index: 0;
}

#dog2 {
  animation: fadeIn2 3s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100px;
  right: -100px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%91_%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%9F.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right bottom;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

@keyframes fadeIn2 {
  0% {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -100px;
    right: -150px;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: -50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>animation</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="div1">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%91_%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%9F.jpg" id="dog1" />

    <div id="dog2" /></div>
  </div>

  <div id="div2">

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `position: relative` to the parent container (`div1` in this case) and `overflow:hidden` to hide the part of the images which goes outside the div. Also remove the `position` property from the keyframes because it's not used.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#div1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: pink;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#dog1 {
  animation: fadeIn 3s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  left: -100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    top: -100px;
    left: -100px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
}

#div2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: purple;
  z-index: 0;
}

#dog2 {
  animation: fadeIn2 3s ease;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -100px;
  right: -100px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%91_%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%9F.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right bottom;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}

@keyframes fadeIn2 {
  0% {
    bottom: -100px;
    right: -150px;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 0px;
    right: -50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>animation</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="div1">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/35/%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%91_%D7%9C%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%9F.jpg" id="dog1" />

    <div id="dog2"><!-- typo here -->
    </div> 
  </div>

  <div id="div2">

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: yes that is exactly what i wanted! Thank you so much :)